# how to fix:My fonts & all wordpress icons that used by @font-face are suddenly disabled

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

how to fix:My fonts & all wordpress icons that used by @font-face are suddenly disabled

icons(define by @font-face) appear as rectangles and fonts(define by @font-face) does not work

I updated the template but it didn't work
the theme is movedo wordpress template

Comment: That means that fonts are not being loaded. Open DevTools (Chrome F12) and see if there are any errors in the console. Did you change your website structure recently? Try with www. and without and see if errors persist.

Comment: (see also your adblocker, it can prevent some third-party resources to be properly loaded)

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of FontAwesome icons disappearing in a WordPress installation is caching plugins. Try to disable all caching plugins and test again.

Additionally you need to ensure that the two URLs found inside of WP > Settings > General are identical.

If that fails, please provide a link where your code appears so that we can at least try to help you.